# Espresso action bar back stopped working in SDK 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-testing, android-espresso

I have functional tests using mainly Espresso and running correctly. Yesterday I tried to migrate to Android 5 Lollipop. I ran the tests but all of the tests using this line of code stopped working on emulator with sdk 21:

```
onView(withContentDescription("Navigate up")).perform(click());
```

Maybe when I am back home I will try Robotium

```
getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
        }
});
```

Anybody found a solution that would work also in Android 4.x? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working"? I've just run all my instrumentation tests with Espresso in Lollipop emulator and they work.

Comment: As I have written "onView(withContentDescription("Navigate up")).perform(click());" doesn't work anymore. Do you use the same line of code in your tests?

Comment: I use onView(allOf(withText("text"), isDisplayed())).perform(click()) and it works. "Doesn't work anymore" - can be anything: crash, app exits, freezing, wait for action...

Comment: I can't access the tests now. I think the test was not working due to "Navigate up" not found... I will try your version and if it works I will accept it. In the meanwhile try to answer this question so that I could accept it. Thx

Comment: One more thing: your test case tests only one Activity or multiple? When multpile there can be synchronization issues betweeen changes across Activities, so Espresso may have problems to obtain views.

Comment: It ain't any sync issue. I was stepping there using debugger and could see the views were ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer created from comment: 
I use:

```
onView(allOf(withText("text"), isDisplayed())).perform(click())
```

and it works as expected.